# fill up time gap when only start dates are available

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
ColA <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3)
ColB <- c("a1","a1","a1","b2","c2","d3")
ColC <-as.Date(c("1999-02-01","2001-03-05","2010-01-01","2005-05-22","2008-07-24","2015-06-09"))
ColD <- c("high","low","middle","middle","high","high")
Questions <- data.frame(ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD)

Desired Output:
ColA ColB ColC        ColD
1    a1   1999-02-01  high
1    a1   1999-02-02  high
....
1    a1   2001-03-04  high
1    a1   2001-03-05  low
.....etc.......
```

What I want to do is to derive and "fill up" the gapes between the Dates where input of other columns changes. So that e.g. ColA = 1 will be the same output in ColD as long as its not "2001-03-05". Ideally it should fill up in days. Any suggestion how to do it? Main issue is here, that ColA and ColB are like a foreign key to be handled. so when a value in either ColA or ColB changes, both need to be evaluated until the present time, while when only ColC or ColD changes, they need to stop where the next date starts. Hope I did explain it right.

Best Regards,
Christian

Comment: i did'nt understand this part : "so when a value in either ColA or ColB changes, both need to be evaluated until the present time", please be more precise

Comment: and how will you fill the dates between rows 3 & 4, in a reverse order?

Comment: @vdep its indeed wrong. I just wanted to State that every unique combination of ColA and ColB must be considered. And if it's the case like in Observation ColA = 1 then you have to think about that more than one observation with the same ColA& ColB combination exists and the values in ColD can change between dates